# Same Storyboard for different screen Sizes without Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, screen, resolution

I've been using different storyboard for different screen sizes. 
Now, I'm updating an old app with only one Storyboard for iPhones and it looks the same appearance as iPhone 5 in different iPhone simulators, without using auto layout. Works well on iPhone6 and 6 plus Simulator.

Can I trust this behaviour or is any simulator bug? Is it due to any Properties project config ?

Comment: Images with arrows indicating the problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... Just not setting any launch screen image for the devices without defined storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You must use auto-layout otherwise it will not work 100%. If you enable auto resize subviews option in storyboard view then it might work upto some extent.